# Heroku node websocket application worker dyno deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku

1. I have a node application which is communicating with an external service via websocket
2. Thus I do not need to bind to any specific port
3. I read in the documentation that I should use a `worker` type Dyno vs. a web type Dyno
4. However I cannot understand how to do so:

4.1 I tried creating a Procfile and adding `worker: node index.js` however when I try and push this I get build errors complaining about not having a heroku.yml file. But I am not using dockers here

Can someone please explain to me exactly how I can setup a Dyno as a worker dyno?

Comment: "I get build errors"—please always include error messages verbatim when asking a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however when I try and push this I get build errors complaining about not having a `heroku.yml` file

This has nothing to do with running worker dynos, or with your `Procfile`. Somehow, your app's [stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack) has been set to `container`.

You can [change your app's stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#migrating-to-a-new-stack) with the `heroku stack:set` command, e.g.

```
heroku stack:set heroku-22
```

The default stack is currently Heroku-22, and that's likely the best choice here. Heroku-20 is still supported, too.

After setting the stack, try deploying again. This should get rid of the `heroku.yml` error and let the build proceed.